# SortableTableView does not wrap height to its content

Tags: c#, android, xaml, xamarin

I am using [SortableTableView](https://github.com/xamarin/XamarinComponents/tree/master/Android/SortableTableView) as my table view and I am having trouble including a TextView right below the component.

[image]

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"   
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <de.codecrafters.tableview.SortableTableView
       android:id="@+id/tableView"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       app:tableView_columnCount="4"
       app:tableView_headerElevation="10" />
   <TextView
       android:id="@+id/txtSummaryRecords"
       android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
       android:text="Summary details goes here"
       android:layout_below="@+id/tableView"
       android:gravity="center_horizontal"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:textColor="?android:attr/colorError" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

However, when I add a static value to the height as below, it displays right below to the table.

```
<de.codecrafters.tableview.SortableTableView
     android:id="@+id/tableView"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="450dp" <--included value
     app:tableView_columnCount="4"
     app:tableView_headerElevation="10" />
```

Result:

[image]

I tried setting`android:layout_height=` to `match_parent` and no difference. Looks like SortableTableView filled through whole screen disregard to the `wrap_content` layout height. Any support would highly appreciate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also found this problem, which seems to be that the default height is already `match_parent`.

If you want the TextView at the bottom,and SortableTableView above it.You could do like below as a workaround.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"   
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">

  <de.codecrafters.tableview.SortableTableView
    android:id="@+id/tableView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@id/toolbar"
    android:layout_above="@+id/txtSummaryRecords"
    app:tableView_columnCount="4"
    app:tableView_headerElevation="10"
    app:tableView_headerColor="@color/primary" />
  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtSummaryRecords"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:text="Summary details goes here"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="?android:attr/colorError" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks @leo, but this approach also has a huge gap between table and the text view.

Comment: @iJay Yes,If you don't have enough data，there will be a gap.But on the other hand, if wrap_content works, when there is enough data.I think the textview will also be invisible, and it will go beyond the screen boundaries.So fixing textview to the bottom of the screen might be a relatively acceptable solution unless you customize the SortableTableView according to its source code.

Comment: Agree with you Leo. Is there a way to override SortableTableView's properties?